# how to add tick icon instead of bullet icon in MUI radio button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-button

i need to add CheckCircleSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircleSharp' instead of bullet icon

```
{res?.map((radiooption, index) => (
<>
<RadioGroup
aria-labelledby="demo-radio-buttons-group-label"
name="radio-buttons-group"
className={classes.radioGroup}
value={value}
onChange={handleChange}
key={radiooption.secondaryRadioName}
>
<FormControlLabel className={classes.radioButton} value= 
{radiooption?.secondaryRadioName} control={<Radio />} label={<span 
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: radiooption?.secondaryRadioName }}/>} 
/>
</RadioGroup>
</>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the  API, you can utilize its `checkedIcon` prop, so the Radio component should looks like this

```
<Radio checkedIcon={<CheckCircleIcon />} />
```

Link to the `checkedIcon` props info: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/radio/#Radio-prop-checkedIcon

CodeSandbox working demo (see line 20): https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cloud-xhylt5?file=/Demo.tsx:718-761

Comment: But how to add in RadioGroup or in FormControlLabel?

Comment: @ArunKrishna According to the RadioGroup API and FormControlLabel API, no option prop is provided. Meaning you need to use `Radio` component to do it the MUI native way. Why would you like to do it in other places btw?

Answer (score 1):

=> You need to add `checkedIcon` property in the control this way:

Sample Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-einstein-cgqfrk?file=/Demo.js

Let me know, if you have any doubt. Thanks.

Comment: But how to add in RadioGroup or in FormControlLabel?

Comment: You need to add in FormControlLabel, this way:           control={<Radio checkedIcon={<CheckCircleOutlineSharpIcon />} />}